# Configure IIS on Small Business Server 2003 to communicate with Apache in local network

Tags: iis-6, apache2, windows-server-2003

I have an IIS 6.x running on my windows 2003 sbs  (Computer A), that is reachable from the internet on port 80 and the SSL port.

I have a second machine (Computer B) running in my local network, where I have running an Apache webserver with several application I want to make accessible from internet.

I added IIRF (Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter) to the IIS and can reach the start pages of my applications (MediaWiki, tracks and so on). if i try to log in at my personal MediaWiki instance i am getting following error "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found."

ps: my IIRF.ini file

---

RewriteLog c:\logs\iirf

RewriteLogLevel 1

IterationLimit 10

MaxMatchCount 10

RewriteEngine ON

StatusInquiry ON

ProxyPass          ^/(.*)$   hxxp://xxxIPinLANxxx/$1

ProxyPassReverse   /         hxxp://xxxIPinLANxxx/